# javascript - odd/even table striping - multiple tables on single page

Tags: javascript

I've got a table design I'm using across multiple tables.  There will be some color differences, but they are determined based on classes.
ex:

```
<table id="table" class="table1"> and <table id="table" class="table2">
```

I want to apply javascript striping to odd rows; however, want it to work on all tables with ID `table` because on some pages there will be multiple tables with the same ID (just different classes).

I've looked at this code,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
 });
```

But it appears to only work on the first table and stops after that.  I saw a code the other day that worked; however, now I can't seem to find it.  Any suggestions on a javascript code that will work across multiple tables, getting the odd rows from each table separately and applying the class to those rows?

If I didn't phrase this correctly, please let me know and I will try to correct.  And I'm not using CSS nth-child to do this because the CSS nth-child doesn't work in IE (at least I havent been able to get it to work).  I need this site to work even in older browsers, which is why I'm going back to JS.  I also need the JS to work in all browsers.

Comment: ids are unique. getting elements by id will only return the first one. You'll need to use a class instead.

Comment: I modified this to add the class, but its not starting the count over for each table separately.  I don't need it to continue counting from the point it left off..http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2 (I need table 2 to the first one)  --- the code is available here: http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :-

```
$("#table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

to

```
$("table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

You can also try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").find("TR:odd").addClass("odd");
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KNmuQ/245/)

In the first solution the original selector will take a group of all of the tr elements contained within table  on the page,  and then taking every other one of that huge set. The later one first creates a group of all the tables and then a sub group of the rows within each table and then takes every other one of the rows in each sub group.

Comment: The 2nd solution is perfect.  I do have a question though, it appears that you have told it to find TR:odd; however, its finding rows 2 and 4 (which by number are even).  I am somewhat new to javascript, and kinda curious why it is finding those rows instead of rows 1 and 3.  This may be a stupid question

Comment: That's because it is using a 0-based array on the rows that are returned by the selector.  So, the 1st row is the "0th" element of the array . . . 0, being even, gets tagged as "even", despite being the 1st element in the array (i.e., technically "odd").

Comment: @talemyn +1 Very well explained. But do you have any documentation link that contains this content. I couldn't find it in JQUERY API DOCUMENTATION. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vivek - Actually, the JQuery API is where I first learned it (after wondering about the weird behavior myself).  It's actually in the first line of the page for both the `:even` and `:odd` selectors :D ( here: http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/ and here: http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/ ).

Answer (score 2):

if you use the ID selector `#<whatever>` then it will only return the first element that matches. you could use `$("table  tr:odd")` or come up with a class to assign all of your tables that indicate it should have alternate row coloring, like `$(".table-striped tr:odd")`

**alternatives**

these examples will work across multiple tables and keep the coloring order the same

```
$('.table-striped').each(function () {
    $('tr:odd', this).addClass('odd');
});

$(".table-striped tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

Comment: so ID can only be assigned to the first occurrence, but classes can be assigned to multiple occurrences on the same page?  I'm asking just for clarification so that I am aware for future coding

Comment: yes. you should only ever be assigning an ID to a single element, it uniquely identifies that element.  a class should be used whenever you are trying to identify multiple elements

Comment: I modified this to add the class, but its not starting the count over for each table separately.  I don't need it to continue counting from the point it left off..http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2 (I need table 2 to look identical to the first one)  --- the code is available here: http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2/edit

Comment: does using `$(".table-striped tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");` work for you? http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/3/edit  give that a shot, if not then you'll have to use `.each`

Comment: $("table").find("TR:odd").addClass("odd"); ended up working (at least so far)  Thank you for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

"Well, you have a fundamental flaw in that approach, in that `id` values must be unique on a page.  So you really shouldn't make the `id` attribute the common "thing" to based the script on.

The good news is that you can skip using the ID and do it based on the tag itself . . . `$("table tr:odd").addClass("odd");` will apply the class to the odd rows of every `<table>` element on the page.

Comment: I modified this to add the class, but its not starting the count over for each table separately.  I don't need it to continue counting from the point it left off..http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2 (I need table 2 to look identical to the first one)  --- the code is available here: http://jsbin.com/ucadiq/2/edit

Comment: Heh . . . yeah, that's an interesting (an unintended by me) side effect of the JQuery that I used for the solution.  The selector is getting all rows from all tables and the filtering the "odd" ones from that group.  By using the `$("table").find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");` solution that Vivek included, you are selecting all of the tables first, and then going through each table and getting all of the rows for that table only, and filtering the "odd" ones.  Apparently it's not useful for what you need, but a good "behavior" tip to file away, in case you need it later.   :)

Answer (score 1):

You got the ID and Class mixed up

```
<table id="table" class="table1">
```

Should be

```
<table id="table1" class="table">
```

and

```
<table id="table" class="table2">
```

Should be

```
<table id="table2" class="table">
```

Your JS should be:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
 });
```

An ID should be unique and apply only once, it is used to identify a specific element. Hence the name 'ID'.

A class is used to find multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

We can use bootstrap. Add class **table-striped** to the table.

Remember do include necessary bootstrap files.